# How can conditions be handled in GCL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, gnu-common-lisp, ansi-common-lisp, condition-system

[`handler-case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_hand_1.htm) is key to handling conditions in Common Lisp, but GCL 2.6.12 on Ubuntu 18.04 considers it to be an undefined function:

```
>(handler-case (error "test") (error (condition) condition))                   
                                                                               
Error: UNDEFINED-FUNCTION :NAME HANDLER-CASE                                   
Fast links are on: do (si::use-fast-links nil) for debugging                   
Signalled by EVAL.                                                             
UNDEFINED-FUNCTION :NAME HANDLER-CASE                                          

Broken at EVAL.  Type :H for Help.                                             
    1  Return to top level.                                                    
>>
```

The same is true for `handler-bind`.

The only function related to handling conditions or errors that is obvious in the GCL manual is the GCL-specific [`universal-error-handler`](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/gcl-doc/gcl-si/System-Definitions.html#index-UNIVERSAL_002dERROR_002dHANDLER).

How can conditions be handled in GCL, preferably in a way that is supported by other Lisps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The situation is explained in the project's [`README.Debian`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gcl.git/tree/gcl/debian/README.Debian):

> [...] The common lisp standard in effect when GCL was first released is known as "Common Lisp, the Language" (CLtL1) after a book by Steele of the same name providing this specification.  Subsequently, a much expanded standard was adopted by the American National Standards Institute (ANSI), which is still considered the definitive common lisp language specification to this day.

[...]

> To toggle the use of the ANSI image, set the environment variable GCL_ANSI to any non-empty string.

([This Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=175331#15) has a little more info.)

`handler-case` requires ANSI support, so on Debian-based systems, GCL needs to be started with the `GCL_ANSI` environment variable set; for example:

```
$ GCL_ANSI=1 gcl
```

To reflect the change, the first line of the startup message changes from:

```
GCL (GNU Common Lisp)  2.6.12 CLtL1    Fri Apr 22 15:51:11 UTC 2016
```

To:

```
GCL (GNU Common Lisp)  2.6.12 ANSI    Fri Apr 22 15:51:11 UTC 2016
```